# Auto Pointer constructor in VC2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, visual-studio-2005, copy-constructor, auto-ptr

I have an auto pointer implementation:

```
template <typename T, bool Arr = false>
class GAutoPtr
{
    T *Ptr;

public:
    typedef GAutoPtr<T, Arr> &AutoPtrRef;

    GAutoPtr(T *ptr = 0)
    {
        Ptr = ptr;
    }

    GAutoPtr(AutoPtrRef p)
    {
        Ptr = p.Release();
    }

    ~GAutoPtr() { Empty(); }
    operator T*() { return Ptr; }
    T *Get() { return Ptr; }
    T *operator->() const { LgiAssert(Ptr); return Ptr; }

    inline void Empty()
    {
        if (Arr)
            delete [] Ptr;
        else
            delete Ptr;
        Ptr = 0;
    }

    AutoPtrRef operator =(GAutoPtr<T> p)
    {
        Empty();
        Ptr = p.Ptr;
        p.Ptr = 0;
        return *this;
    }

    void Reset(T *p)
    {
        if (p != Ptr)
        {
            Empty();
            Ptr = p;
        }
    }

    T *Release()
    {
        T *p = Ptr;
        Ptr = 0;
        return p;
    }
};

typedef GAutoPtr<char, true> GAutoString;
typedef GAutoPtr<char16, true> GAutoWString;
```

And that works fine in Visual C++ 6. However in Visual C++ 2005 or 2008 I can't return an auto pointer from a function without things going horribly wrong.

e.g.

```
GAutoString Func()
{
    char *s = new char[4];
    strcpy(s, "asd");
    return s;
}

int main()
{
    GAutoString a = Func();
    /// a.Ptr is now garbage
}
```

What happens is that the compiler creates a temporary GAutoString to hold the return value for the function, and then in passing that to the variable 'a' on the stack calles the operator T*() of the temp variable, and then the GAutoPtr(T *ptr = 0) constructor, instead of just using the copy constructor: GAutoPtr(AutoPtrRef p)

This results in the temp auto ptr deleting the memory and 'a' holding a pointer to the freed memory.

However in VC6 it DOES call the right constructor. Now in saying all this I also use gcc on Linux and Mac, so whatever code I write needs to work there too. VC2008 prevents you from using a non-const by value variable in the copy constructor. Also I don't want "const" anyway, because the copy constructor takes ownership of the memory block which removes ownership from the object being copied... thus modifying it.

How can I make this work in VC 2005/2008?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did this even compile under a recent g++?  I tried it on my MacBook Pro and:

```
xxx.cpp: In function ‘AutoString func()’:
xxx.cpp:52: error: no matching function for call to ‘AutoPtr<char, true>::AutoPtr(AutoString)’
xxx.cpp:12: note: candidates are: AutoPtr<T, isArray>::AutoPtr(AutoPtr<T, isArray>&) [with T = char, bool isArray = true]
xxx.cpp:9: note:                 AutoPtr<T, isArray>::AutoPtr(T*) [with T = char, bool isArray = true]
xxx.cpp:52: error:   initializing temporary from result of ‘AutoPtr<T, isArray>::AutoPtr(T*) [with T = char, bool isArray = true]’
```

The only way that I can get this to compile is by making the copy constructor take a `const` reference which is what I had suspected. It looks like [Herb Sutter posted about something very similar](http://herbsutter.wordpress.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/) to this in his most recent GotW. I wouldn't try to replicate the ownership transfer semantic of `std::auto_ptr` without a very good reason. You might want to look at the various goodies in [Boost.SmartPtr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm). If possible, use them instead.

If you can't Boost for whatever reason, then read your favorite `std::auto_ptr` implementation and pay particular attention to the `std::auto_ptr_ref` class. Once you understand why it is there and exactly how it does what it does, then go back and write an auto-ptr class. This class exists to get around the problem that you are seeing. IIRC, this is discussed in some detail in [Josuttis': The Standard C++ Library](http://www.josuttis.com/libbook/auto_ptr.html). I think that is where I really understood it for the first time.

Comment: Ending up needing more than the 'explicit' keyword, so I've distilled a solution from STL using the auto_ptr_ref class. So far so good.

Answer (score 1):

You could mark the constructor that takes the T* argument with the "explicit" keyword.  I've verified that this works and prevents the creation of the spurious temporary object too, a performance enhancement. Anyone using that constructor could no longer rely on compiler type conversion rules, though.  For example, you function would change to this:

```
GAutoString Func()
{
    char *s = new char[4];
    strcpy(s, "asd");
    return GAutoString(s);
}
```

It's annoying, but I don't think that is necessarily a bad thing in this case as automatic type conversions can be confusing.

Comment: Yeah that works. I do have to clean up a new automatic convertsions like you said... but I'd rather that than apps the crash ;)